# kubernetes: Log in to dashboard as admin

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-security

I have deployed a `k8s` cluster to `aws` using `kops`.

The process created a `~./kube/config` file with the following structure:

```
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: 
      <data_here>
  name: <cluster_name>
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: <cluster_name>
    user: <cluster_name>
  name: <cluster_name>l
current-context: <cluster_name>
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: <cluster_name>
  user:
    as-user-extra: {}
    client-certificate-data:
    <client_certificate_data>
    client-key-data: 
    <client-key-data>
    password: <some-password>
    username: admin
- name:<cluster-name>-basic-auth
  user:
    as-user-extra: {}
    password: <some-password>
    username: admin
```

When (after creating the dashboard) I perform `kube proxy` and try to access it via localhost, I am prompted with the following screen:

[image]

**1**: Why when I point the file browser to the above created `~./kube/config` file I get

> Authentication failed

**2**: When I provide the `password` included in the `~./kube/config` file, I do log in but not as an administrator (e.g. I am unable to view compute resources on the pods)

Answer (score 1):

You can give the admin access by running this yaml file :

```
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
metadata:
  name: dashboard
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: cluster-admin
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: kubernetes-dashboard
  namespace: kube-system
```

This will allow access to the kubernetes dashboard. But this will give open access, you need to do skip the login after running this. 
more details can be found here https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/wiki/Access-control

Comment: How does one "run" the YAML file?

Comment: `kubectl apply -f some_file.yaml`